# When to use render and when to use redirect if you want to create login with session

Tags: django

so i want to make a login with a session , but i dont know when to use render or when to use redirect , here's the code

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':         
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            guest = User.objects.get(username=username)
            role = guest.role
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  
            if user is not None: 
                if role == 'Business Analyst':
                    login(request, user)
                    request.session['username'] = username
                    return render(request,'index.html',{"username":username})
                    #return redirect('/home')
                elif role == 'Admin':
                    login(request, user)
                    request.session['username'] = username
                    #return redirect('/manageuser/')
                elif role == 'Manager':
                    login(request, user)
                    request.session['username'] = username
                   # return redirect('/approvallist/')
                elif role == 'Segment Manager':
                    login(request, user)
                    request.session['username'] = username
                    #return redirect('/approvallist/')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password!")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password!")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,"login.html",{"form":form})

def index_view(request):
    #if request.session.has_key('username'):
    #    username = request.session['username']
    #    return render(request,'index.html',{"username":username})
    #else:
    #    return render(request,'login.html',{})
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

am i doing this right? about the use of return render? or i must use return redirect?

Comment: You can use 'redirect' to direct the user to any existing function, and use 'render' to print pages to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass some context to the template that time you can use render function. If there is no context and going to display some page at that time you can use redirect function.you can put login, request["session"] outside the if condition cause its duplicated multiple times in your code. A redirect function will call a view mapped with url and return the template with context.
That depends on the requirement.